# Get filesize of each file in listview

Tags: vb.net

net

I wanna ask how to fix this code? It's working but it doesn't show the the size symbol (e.g. 100GB) only numbers are showing.

I wanna know and show the file size of each .ts file I loaded to listview

Here's the code:

```
 For Each file As String In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(txtInputFolder.Text, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ts")

        Dim fileSize As Decimal = Format(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(file).Length / 1048576.0, "#,##0.00")

        Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(FileIO.FileSystem.GetName(file))

        ListView1.BeginUpdate()

        item.SubItems.Add(FileIO.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(file).DirectoryName)

        item.SubItems.Add(fileSize))

        ListView1.EndUpdate()
    Next
    For Each column As ColumnHeader In ListView1.Columns
        column.Width = -1
    Next
```

Comment: First things first, the way you're adding the items is bad. You don't call `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` inside a loop. You call `BeginUpdate` once, add all the items, then call `EndUpdate` once. The documentation even has a code example so there's simply no excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your code should look like:

```vb
Dim folderPath = txtInputFolder.Text
Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)

ListView1.BeginUpdate()

For Each file In folder.EnumerateFiles("*.ts")
    ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({file.Name,
                                          folderPath,
                                          (file.Length / (1024 ^ 3)).ToString("#,0.00 GB")}))
Next

ListView1.EndUpdate()
```

There are a few points to note.

1. This code uses the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` classes,
   which gives you direct access to information including file size.
2. It calls `EnumerateFiles` rather than `GetFiles`, as it is
   more efficient if you only want to use the data once.
3. It uses the `ListView` methods correctly.
4. It uses a cleaner method of adding an item with subitems.
5. It uses the folder path that you already have rather than getting it from the file path, as it will be the same every time anyway.
6. It formats your number in a more efficient way.
7. Most importantly, it adds the unit to the number as part of the format.

Comment: Wow thank you for the correction with my codes. 
You code really help a lot for me to understand more about using the listview.

Comment: I have a little problem.
The result of file size inside the listview are all the same 0.00GB

Comment: Sorry yeah I figure it out with your code above. I just changed the file.length to 
(file.Length / (1024 ^ 2)).ToString("#,0.00 MB")}))

Since all the .ts file are mb size only so that code worked :)

Comment: It's up to you but I would be inclined to adapt the code provided in the other answer in order to use the optimal units based on the actual file size. I'd suggest a method that takes a `Long` and outputs the formatted `String`.

Answer (score 0):

A long ago I had stuck here where you're currently. There you go (meets your requirement too):

```
Dim file = IO.File.Open("yourPath", FileMode.Open)
Dim fileSize = file.Length()

If fileSize > 1024 ^ 3 Then
    Label3.Text = "File Size: " + Format(fileSize / 1024 ^ 3, "0.00").ToString + " GB"

ElseIf fileSize > 1024 ^ 2 Then
    Label3.Text = "File Size: " + Format(fileSize / 1024 ^ 2, "0.00").ToString + " MB"

ElseIf fileSize > 1024 Then
    Label3.Text = "File Size: " + Format(fileSize / 1024, "0.00").ToString + " KB"

Else
    Label3.Text = "File Size: " + Format(file, "0").ToString + " Byte"

    If fileSize > 1 Then
        Label3.Text += "s"
    End If
End If
```

This code is designed to detect and assign GB, MB, KB & bytes prefixes.

Comment: file is a FileStream which should be disposed. It is not necessary to Open a file to get its size. See the FileInfo class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netcore-3.1